# Ошибка при построении query

Tags: postgresql

Вывести список работников, которые работают со своими руководителями в разных отделениях, включая имена и отделения как работников, так и руководителей

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, A.city, B.city
FROM SalesReps A, SalesReps B
JOIN Offices A ON A.rep_office = A.office
JOIN Offices B ON B.rep_office = B.office 
WHERE A.manager = B.empl_num
```

```
ERROR: column a.rep_office does not exist LINE 3: JOIN Offices A ON A.rep_office = C.office ^ HINT: There is a column named "rep_office" in table "a", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должен быть результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так. Конечно с такими вопросами надо давать код для создания и заполнения таблиц. В уме гарантированно правильно решит далеко не каждый, а вбивать руками за вас и проверять никто не захочет.

```
SELECT A.name, oa.city, B.name, ob.city
FROM SalesReps A
JOIN Offices oa ON A.rep_office = oa.office
JOIN SalesReps B on A.manager = B.empl_name and B.rep_office != A.rep_office
JOIN Offices ob ON B.rep_office = ob.office
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас что то странное с переименованием:
Не уверен, что это уже рабочий вариант, но точно решает вашу проблему -

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, A.city, B.city
FROM SalesReps as A, SalesReps as B
JOIN Offices ON A.rep_office = A.office
JOIN Offices ON B.rep_office = B.office 
WHERE A.manager = B.empl_num
```